# Is there a max speed in Forge2D

Tags: flutter, flame, forge2d

When I try to do `applyForce` or `applyLinearImpulse`, I can only get a slow (but stable) speed regardless of how much force I add. Is there a max speed that is applied and restricting my bodies from going faster? I want to be able to have a bullet shooting effect.

I have checked some [tutorial](https://www.yayocode.com/2022/08/flame-forces-impulses-linear-velocity.html), but the velocity still seems too slow, even if I set `body.linearVelocity = Vector2(5000, -5000);` it moves slow.

```
  @override
  bool onTapDown(TapDownInfo info) {
    body.applyLinearImpulse(Vector2(5, -1) * 1000000000);
    return false;
  }
```

gravity is zero, and here is body data:

```
  @override
  Body createBody() {
    final Shape shape = CircleShape()..radius = 30;
    final bodyDef = BodyDef(
      userData: this,
        angularDamping: 0,
      position: Vector2(100, 500),
      type: BodyType.dynamic,
    );
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(shape)
      ..shape = shape
      ..restitution = 1
      ..density = 0.0001 
      ..friction = 0; 

    return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
  }
```

thank you!

Comment: Thanks for reading my article. Another important thing to note here is that Forge2D units are meters and seconds. When you create a ball with a radius of 30, it means it is a ball with a 60-meter diameter. And when you set the speed to 5000. It means this body will be moving at 18,000km/h. Using such high values may create unexpected behaviors

Comment: Hi Arellano, thanks for these info, it indeed helps me learning flame:)

Comment: Could you find it out, i am trying to create a bouncing ball but it is slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to that you have set the zoom level to 1, instead of 10 which is the default. This makes the bodies hit the top speed very quickly, so instead you should just make the bodies smaller and zoom in on them. This is not only Forge2D specific, but applies to pretty much all ports of box2d and box2d itself. You can read more about it [here](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed).

Comment: I have made the zoom level to 20 and more with the same issue still

Comment: @AliNour we'd need more code to debug that, I recommend that you join our Discord or post a new stack overflow question with your code.